# Could be voltage between the two ends of a wire placed vertically?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, electrostatics, newtonian-gravity, voltage

One could think that gravity pushes down the free electrons inside the metal of the wire until there is enough positive charge (on the top end) to compensate the gravity force. If this happens, then there should be a voltage between the two ends, which should disappear when the wire is placed horizontally. I'm asking if this phenomenon has been observed or if it doesn't exist for some other reasons.

Answer (score 3):

Of the four fundamental forces in nature, gravity is by far the weakest. In fact the electromagnetic force is about 10$^{37}$ times stronger than the force of gravity.  That means gravity has negligible effect on the free electrons compared to the electromagnetic force.

Hope this helps.

Comment: So do you think the effect would be negligible also on a planet with a $100g$ gravity?

Comment: @Landau That's only two orders of magnitude greater than the earth. As I said, electromagnetic forces are 37 orders of magnitude greater than gravitational forces. So, what do you think?

Comment: I'm not sure it is right to say that on free electrons acts a net electromagnetic force which is $10^{37}$ times stronger than gravity. I would say that on each free electron act a lot of strong forces, and if you add them all you won't find such a great force, since there will be some compensation phenomena. For this reason I think that if gravity is high enough then the voltage could appear.

Comment: You are free to think what you want but IMO the force of gravity in your example is irrelevant. With that I am ending this discussion